# Images in html table - set both heigth and width fit to screen

Tags: html, css

Im working on a starting page in html to click on logos for links to the webpages and some search bars. I used tables to place the pictures. Thats's all working fine so far, but even after hours of searching and trying out dozens of different combinations of attributes I just can't figure out how to do a proper layout.

Screenshot,
[image: screenshot image]

I want to have it as follows:

- The banner on the top over the full width
- The search bars with logo taking each 50% width
- The bottom row (5 images) taking each 20% width

This should result in a such a layout:

```
 _____________________________
|_____________________________|
|______________|______________|
|______________|______________|
|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

Not a big problem so far, but the images get different heigths depending on the logo ratio and everything gets messed up. The table is then higher than 100% and a scroll bar appears. So I want to limit each rows heigth to a percentage adding up to 100% in total.

When I resize the browser window it shall also keep the aspect and resize the pictures, so that no scroll bars appear.
Somehow I was never able to achieve all of this at the same time, as I could either set heigth or width, but not both at the same time. Can anybody help me with the right way of setting all the heigth/width/min-heigth/max-heigth/..... attributes? I'd be very thankful :)

Here I attached the current version. I just replaced the pictures with dummy pictures, because they are saved local:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Startseite</title>
<style>
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

input {
    font-size: 20pt;
    width: 90%;
    align: center;
    }
    
table {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    }
    
img {
    object-fit: contain
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>


<table width="100%" height="100%">

    <tr height="inherit">
        <td colspan="10">
            <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/300/746/png-transparent-banner-banner-ribbon-watercolor-painting-miscellaneous-angle.png" width="100%" height="auto"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="inherit">
        
        <td colspan="5" width="50%" height="inherit">
            <form method="GET" action="http://www.google.de/search">
            <table height="inherit"><tr height="inherit">
            <td width="30%" height="inherit">
                <a href="http://www.google.de" height="inherit">
                <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" align="center">
            <input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" value="">
            </td></tr></table>
            </form>
        </td>
        
        <td colspan="5" width="50%">
            <form method="GET" action="http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search">
            <table><tr>
            <td width="30%">
                <a href="http://www.linguee.de" >
                <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" align="center">
            <input type="text" name="query" maxlength="255" value="">
            </td></tr></table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr height="inherit">
    <tr height="inherit">
        <td colspan="5" width="50%">
            <form method="GET" action="http://www.youtube.com/results">
            <table><tr>
            <td width="30%">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/?gl=DE" >
                <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" align="center">
            <input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" value="" >
            </td></tr></table>
            </form>
        </td>   
        <td colspan="5" width="50%">

            <table><tr>
            <td width="30%" align="center">
                <a href="http://www.deepl.com" >
                <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" align="center">
            <input type="text" name="DeepLquery" maxlength="255" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) window.location.href = 'http://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/' + document.getElementsByName('DeepLquery')[0].value;">
            </td></tr></table>
        </td>       
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="20%">
            <a href="http://www.smile.amazon.de" >
            <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
            </a>        
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="20%">
            <a href="http://www.ebay.de" >
            <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
            </a>        
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="20%">
            <a href="http://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de" >
            <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
            </a>        
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="20%">
            <a href="http://www.google.de/maps" >
            <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
            </a>        
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="20%">
            <a href="http://www.chordify.net" >
            <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
            </a>        
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize the CSS max-height, max-width to contain them within the table rows. So if after you calculate the row height to be 50px, you may specify a class on the image or just style images within this table record to be a max-height < 50px.

There is [another post that handles a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797763/html5-css-equal-height-columns-not-working-with-images-table-table-cell-method).

You may also strictly specify the cell sizes as mentioned in this [post on a similar issue sans images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869420/making-a-table-cell-constant-width-height).